# After azure publish my domain gives 403 error

Tags: azure, deployment, appdomain

I have deployed my web application to azure.
And now it is working as expected for xxx.azurewebsites.net
Then I have configured for my domain.
Now it gives the following

> "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied." error for xxx.com

When I click browse from azure it redirects to xxx.com
What can be the problem ?

Comment: How did you configure for your domain, you need to give us a little detail here man, don't keep us in the dark.

Comment: omg it was because A record of dns was somehow removed from my other hosting account! but why!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do would be to check if the DNS records are getting updated properly.

Check a DNS site such as this - http://mxtoolbox.com/DnsLookup.aspx

Second, fix any A record or DNS record issues (you may have re add them or delete them, then add them back).

Third, come back to the custom domains section. Here, by default, there will be your xxx.azurewebsites.com something. Along with that, your custom domain should also be visible. If not, then add it back.

Note, sometimes, you may have to wait almost 1 hour after updating your DNS records for Azure to validate your custom domain. Just remember that.